# QT play internet radio

Tags: qt, audio-streaming, internet-radio

i have problem when want play internet radio.
My example is simple with one button play radio stations.

I can play radio streaming when MP3 like
http://mms-live.online.no/p4_norge_mp3_mq
but cannot play 
http://naxidigital128.kbcnet.rs:8000/listen.pls

My pc Win7 64 and QT 5.5.1
I have installed codec.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaPlaylist>
#include <QtMultimedia/QMultimedia>
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaPlayer>
#include <QString>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
_playList = new QMediaPlaylist(this);
_isPlaying=false;
_player = new QMediaPlayer(0,QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
   delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
// not work other host 
//QString sources = "http://mms-live.online.no/p4_norge_mp3_mq";
// not work with 
//erorr DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 80040218
QString sources = "http://naxidigital128.kbcnet.rs:8000/listen.pls";
_player->setMedia(QMediaContent(sources));
_player->play();
}
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Do you get an error? Did you capture any network traffic with Wireshark?

Comment: Error
DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 80040218 
I try play this url other player is work. And use wireshark but not found nothing interesting.

Answer (score 0):

`0x80040218` (a/k/a `VFW_E_CANNOT_RENDER`) is a generic error whose description is:

> No combination of filters could be found to render the stream.

The usual cause is that the application cannot decode the media stream as it lacks decoding components, such as codec for this video. A solution is to check and install the codec for this video stream.